# I installed netron with `snap install netron` but I don't know how to run netron

Tags: snap

As https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron shows, I installed netron viewer by `snap install netron` and it is installed.
But how do I run netron viewer?
I see under /var/lib/spapd/snaps directory both netron_115.snap and netron_116.
If I try `netron`, the shell says `command not found`. and if I try `snap install netron`, it says `snap netron is already installed`.
How can I run netron? (I can run it on windows though).
BTW, I hate those web sites not telling me the easist basic instructions and make people search the web for so long time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`snap list` gives you the list of installed packages on your machine.

If you see `netron` in the list, it means it is installed.

The installed packages are located in `/snap/bin`.

```
$ ls /snap/bin
```

To run netron type:

```
$ /snap/bin/netron
```

If you add `/snap/bin` to your `PATH`, then just running `netron` in the command line should load it for you.

Comment: hi! welcome! I've long forgotten this question, actually I could download the netron executable and run it directly.